# ODK Collect - Google Drive default authentication

Tags: android, google-drive-api, odk

i have successfully setup ODK Collect into my android app. I can setup my tom cat credentials easily from the settings xml. However when i try to switch to google drive, i need to setup the google account from my phone. Is it possible to setin default email and password for fetching questionaires.

```
<string-array name="protocol_entry_values">
    <item>@string/protocol_odk_default</item>
    <item>@string/protocol_google_sheets</item>
    <item>@string/protocol_other</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="protocol_entries">
    <item>@string/server_platform_odk_aggregate</item>
    <item>@string/server_platform_google_sheets</item>
    <item>@string/server_platform_other</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: You should be reading the users permissions from the sign in not asking them to set a login and password.   Google does not allow for client login anymore your going to have to Authenticate your users.

Comment: So i have a normal auth for my users, however have setup a google drive account that contains my xml forms for my users. However to be able to access these forms from google-drive. Each user has to signin to the gmail account that contains the forms. I was wondering if it was possible for me to authorize ODK collect to fetch these forms from google-drive without having my users manually setup the google account to connect them to google-drive.

Comment: are all the users going to be useing the same files?

Comment: Yes, i'll have a parent google account where all xml questionaires are stored

Comment: check out service accounts then sounds like this may be a good fit

Comment: Ok thanks let me check that & see if it works for me

Comment: Just read the documentation and seems like a great fit for what i'm trying to archive thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access users google drive accounts files stored on that then you need to use Oauth2.

However if you are trying to access a central google drive account one that you as the developer has controller over you should look into service accounts.   Service accounts are like a dummy user it has its own drive account and you can share a folder on your drive account with it.  Its pre authorized so it always has access you dont have to worry about authenticating it.